# Angular 4: "Cannot find name 'require'

Tags: angular, webpack

I am building an app with **Angular 4** and **webpack**.

I have the following in one of my components:

```
ngOnInit() {
    require('/assets/js/regular-expresions.js');
}
```

When I attempt to compile, I get:

> ERROR in
>   C:/SRC/Sandbox/eat-sleep-code.com/src/app/content.component.ts (21,9):
>   Cannot find name 'require'.

I have ran `npm install @types/node --save-dev` and updated my tsconfig.json to look like:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

But alas, the same error keeps getting thrown.  Any ideas?

---

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "eat-sleep-code.com",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.69",
    "angularfire2": "^2.0.0-beta.8",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^3.7.8",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.16.0",
    "ng2-gist": "^1.0.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "^6.0.2",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.4",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.69",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.2",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: try removing `types` and `typeRoots` from `tsconfig`

Comment: Try using import instead. See the docs for using Webpack with Angular here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html

Comment: @DeborahK, as I understand, he doesn't want TS to process `require`, he leaves it for `webpack`

Comment: @DeborahK I get "an import declaration can only be used in a namespace or module" because this is in an ngOnInit

Comment: @Maximus removing `types` and `typeRoots` had no effect.   The same "Cannot find name 'require'" error.

Comment: @eat-sleep-code, create a plunker

Comment: The import statement would not go inside the ngOnIt ... it would need to be at the top. Have you looked at the documentation link I posted?

Comment: @Maximus Of?  The whole app?  How in the world do I do that?  Recreate each file one by one?

Comment: @DeborahK I have.   But, I am looking to dynamically load a script so it can't be static.  The '/assets/js/regular-expresions.js' would be replaced with a variable.

Comment: For electron + angular 2/4 see: stackoverflow.com/a/47364843/5248229

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`require()` is not advisable for a few reasons.  One, it will "break" the effectiveness of tree-shaking in webpack 2 and two, it will prevent proper code splitting.

A far better alternative is to use webpack's implementation of `System.import`:

```
System.import('/assets/js/regular-expresions.js').then(file => {
   // perform additional interactions after the resource has been asynchronously fetched
});
```

In order to satisfy the Typescript compiler (as you have found), you will need to tell it that `System` is an acceptable variable by declaring it:

```
declare var System: any;
```

You can either add this line to your component if you only intend to reference it once, or you can add it to the `typings.d.ts` type definition file to enable its use throughout your app.  Note that if you change the typings file, you will need to restart the `ng serve` session.

This satisfies the compiler at build time and it gets hijacked at runtime by the build system, patching the call through into Webpack's `System.import`.

Webpack in turn will check to see if it has a chunk that satisfy the requested file and, if it does not, it will dynamically create a script tag and insert it into the head, loading the file with the `async` attribute, which is what occurs in this case.

Once the file loads, it will be parsed and executed.  However, if you want to interact with any part of it via the async `.then()` callback, your file will need to export anything you wish to invoke, such as:

```
export function test() {
    console.log('we called test');
}
```

This will expose the `.test()` function to your callback handler:

```
System.import('/assets/js/regular-expresions.js').then(file => {
   file.test();
});
```

Comment: Slight problem, I cannot get System.import to work with a variable.  I am using this syntax `System.import(``assets/js/${script}``};` and it doesn't work.   If I hardcode it to `System.import(``assets/js/regular-expressions.js``};` it loads the file just fine.

Comment: That's really a separate question but it's most likely an issue with how you're creating the string. If you manually concatenate does the problem go away?

Comment: I opened a separate question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43507816/angular-4-with-webpack-2-dynamically-loading-scripts

Comment: How about if I import JS library into my project?

Comment: @tjvg1991 I'm not sure what you're trying to ask. ES6 imports are nearly always preferred, but that isn't the topic of this answer.

Comment: whats `System` here?  Trying to use this in my ionic app.  Thanks

Answer (score 47):

Try adding `declare var require: any;` on top.

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: This! This is what i was looking for

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: @zixia This is a hack.

Comment: @J.Money hack..!! why ?

Comment: @saurabh With typescript properly configured `require` will have a type. Declaring `require` as an any type is not solving the actual problem.

Comment: @J.Money I think the actual problem has been solved, I am able to use same `.js` file in `nodeJS` and in `Angular`

Answer (score 7):

Try these steps to fix the error

1. `npm install --save-dev @types/webpack-env`
2. Update your tsconfig.json with the following under compilerOptions:

   ```
   "types": [
       "webpack-env"
   ]
   ```

3.Now go to tsconfig.app.json and add this

```
"compilerOptions": {
 
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

try below,

```
<any>require('/assets/js/regular-expresions.js')
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: With this I still get the 'Cannot find name 'require'. error

Answer (score 0):

try

```
compilerOptions: {
   ...
   "typeRoots": [ "../node_modules/@types" ],
   ...
}
```

in tsconfig.json