# Use a require for import module in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I need to use this lib in Ionic: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken
It's to sign a token (yes, I need to sign a jwt in my front end)

It was working in Ionic 3! I was using the "declare var require: any;" trick from this post: [Angular 4: "Cannot find name 'require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476135/angular-4-cannot-find-name-require)

All was perfect, good

But i am now in Ionic 4 and... Nothing!
It's compile, ok, great, but I always had this error:

```
ERROR Error: "Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: obj is not an object or null
```

If a use a simple js file with the same code to sign a token (and run this file just with node), it's also work!

I only have this issue on Ionic 4. But not on previous version Ionic 3

If there are any recommendations on angular/ionic libraries to sign a token (instead of jsonwebtoken), that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Try to install types for the `jsonwebtoken` library:
`npm i @types/jsonwebtoken`

And then import it with the ES6 style:
`import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';`
instead of `require...`

Comment: and I still must have the original jsonwebtoken, right?

I have tested, still doesn't work
"TypeError: obj is not an object or null"
with import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
(yes because jsonwebtoken haven't default export)

what must I have in my tsconfig?
module: es6?
types: ["nodes"] ?

Comment: I also have tried with another @types/...
the @types/jws
And always the same error

Comment: @Caribou here I tried it out https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-qkrrfy and it looks like it works. All I did just installed `jsonwebtoken` and `@types/jsonwebtoken` as I wrote in the answer and imported it exactly like in the answer. If you open the console, you'll see the `jwt` object with it's functions and stuff. Maybe your error is somewhere else?

Comment: the difference is typescript v2 (I have v3 I can't past to v2 for angular 7)

or maybe with the tsconfig file
I will continue to search