# How to fix webpack "Module not found" error for optional transitive dependency?

Tags: webpack, modulenotfounderror, transitive-dependency

I have come across the following issue, one of the software libraries I'm using has an optional dependency on 'web-worker'. If the web-worker package is available it will use it, if it cannot find the web-worker package, it will use an alternative code path that does not use the web-worker package.

The problem I run into is that when trying to create an angular build, it will give the following error.

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'web-worker' in 'C:\Gitdata\project\dev\angular\node_modules\elkjs\lib'

If I check the main.js file from this package, almost the first thing it does is check if web-worker is available, if it's not it will not try to load web-worker.

```js
    var workerThreadsExist = false;
    try {
      require.resolve('web-worker');
      workerThreadsExist = true;
    } catch (e) {}

    // user requested a worker
    if (options.workerUrl) {
      if (workerThreadsExist) {
        var Worker = require('web-worker');
        optionsClone.workerFactory = function (url) {
          return new Worker(url);
        };
      } else {
        console.warn('Web worker requested but \'web-worker\' package not installed. \nConsider installing the package or pass your own \'workerFactory\' to ELK\'s constructor.\n... Falling back to non-web worker version.');
      }
    }
```

So even though the code flow will never require('web-worker') when it's not available, for some reason I still get the error when trying to build my application.

If I change

> if (options.workerUrl)

into

> if (false)

It still gives me the Module not found error, the only way to get rid of the error is to install the package or remove the

> var Worker = require('web-worker');

line.

How can I tell angular or webpack to ignore this 1 missing package?

Comment: Do you use nodejs? it's nodejs function. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43477099/5468463

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can tell webpack to ignore the `web-worker` module that `elkjs` is trying to `require` with the [`webpack.IgnorePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/ignore-plugin/).

Inside your `webpack.config.js`:

```js
{
  plugins: [
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin({
      resourceRegExp: /web-worker/,
      contextRegExp: /elkjs\/lib$/,
    })
  ]
}
```

Which should tell webpack to ignore any require statement for `web-worker` within a directory path ending in `elkjs/lib`.