# setting __webpack_public_path__ after adding module federation with import

Tags: angular, webpack-module-federation

Because of the structure of our app inside a native website, I had to set the `__webpack_public_path__` .

But now in the new module federation setup for angular the bootstrap.ts script is imported and the `__webpack_public_path__` is not set anymore.

Is there a way I can set the **webpack_public_path** during runtime with the latest way of hoisting the bootstrap.ts?

main.ts:

```
import('./bootstrap').catch(err => console.error(err));
```

bootstrap.ts

```
const getBaseOfModules = (script: string): string => {
  const src = document.querySelector<HTMLScriptElement>(`[src*="${script}"]`).src;
  return `${src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'))}/`;
};
__webpack_public_path__ = getBaseOfModules('main');

initAngularApp();
```

The main.js file and other lazy loaded modules are served at http://some/deep/path/main.js

It looks like angular gets the path based from the url of the last js file.

Addition:
I have tried this according to documentation.. but that doesnt work'.
This script will be loaded also inside a lazyloaded module.

publicpath.ts

```js
declare let __webpack_public_path__;

const getBaseOfModules = (script: string): string => {
  const src = document.querySelector<HTMLScriptElement>(`[src*="${script}"]`).src;
  return `${src.substring(0, src.lastIndexOf('/'))}/`;
};

// set the on the fly public path absolute for module lazy loading see https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/
export default __webpack_public_path__ = getBaseOfModules('main');
```

main.ts

```js
import('@lib-utils/public-path');
import('./bootstrap').catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.. I need to use this solution: [Angular 4: "Cannot find name 'require'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43476135/angular-4-cannot-find-name-require)
using require or System.import

Comment: Possible to share sample snippet please